# Looking for clarification regarding ansible variable precedence

Tags: ansible

I have the following ansible setup:

*ansible_test/playbooks/roles/main/main.yml*

```
- name: hello world
  hosts: all
  
  tasks:
  - name: hello!
    shell: echo "test"

  - name: display config
    debug:
      msg: "testvar is {{ hostvars['localhost']['testvar'] }}"
```

*ansible_test/playbooks/inventory/hosts*

```
[main]
localhost

[main:vars]
testvar=99
```

*ansible-test/playbooks/inventory/group_vars/all/main.yml*

```
testvar: 77
```

Now, when I modify the hosts file to the following:

```
[main]
localhost testvar=88

[main:vars]
testvar=99
```

I get an output of "testvar is 88". However, when I remove this, I get "testvar is 77" instead of the expected "testvar is 99".

When I add "testvar: 101" to a file: `ansible_test/playbooks/inventory/host_vars/localhost.yml`, I get an output of "testvar is 101".

I am running the command:

```
/usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i playbooks/inventory/hosts playbooks/roles/main/main.yml --connection=local -vvvv
```

Why is this? Shouldn't this host-group definition still take precedence over group_vars?

[image]

Comment: The only host in `test_group` is called `test_var`, which is also the name of the var your assign in your role and inventory for `host_name` belonging to `different_group`. This is all really confusing. But since I guess your are running your test against `host_name`,  the result you describe looks rather coherent: when `different_group` exists, it takes value defined in its group vars, when not, the default value in your role. Can you please double check all this, retest after your fix the eventual typo and see if it fixes your issue ? Thanks.

Comment: Yup sorry I am running against host_name and am trying to determine which value for test_var it will pick up in it’s hostvars.

Comment: But your inventory is still declaring `host_name` in a single group, not two.

Comment: `[test_group]\ntest_var` <= This is declaring a host called `test_var` (**not** `host_name`) in group `test_group`

Comment: Ah ok fixed sorry. Didn’t notice. In my actual code I did not have this typo.

Comment: Well now your fixed-it try again, and your problem is gone.

Comment: I still have this issue. The typo was not present in my actual code.

Comment: Please make this an [MCVE](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and please double check it before posting to avoid loosing time on typos.

Comment: @Zeitounator added

Comment: Your `tasks/main.yml` file in your role is a full playbook while it should be a task list only. You're not using your role anywhere: the defaults should not be loaded which is not coherent with your above example. Your group now has a dash in its name (in place of an underscore) which is totally deprecated and should at least issue a warning if not an error depending on your ansible version... well so many issues to even try to give an answer. Read the documentation about roles and inventories. If your have a lot of vars, put them in a `group_vars/group_name.yml` file. Good luck.

Comment: @Zeitounator I am not sure what you mean. The code I supplied works fine locally and my issue is with variable precedence. My question is why am I getting `testvar is 77` rather than `testvar is 99`. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me understand why this is. I have already gone through the documentation to try and get an answer for this before posting. Furthermore, my issue was not "caused by a typo" so I am unsure why you are voting to close it on this basis.

Comment: I precisely mean that when your craft a coherent and correct example, it works exactly as expected => https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/066c5a64fad630d8e2ed3d155b731e6b

Comment: But when you say "coherent and correct", I do not understand what is wrong with my example given that it works locally. Additionally, this is a mcve based on a much larger project using an ansible build system in which I am experiencing the same confusion. In your example, it looks like you use task defaults rather than group vars.

Comment: `I do not understand what is wrong with my example` => then re-read carefully my previous comments: your are not using your role as you should, your `tasks/main.yml` would fire an error if you would anyway. There have been several typos you regularly corrected so we can legitimately suspect this is not exactly the example your are running. Moreover, my example in my gist which does exactly what your are trying to do and uses a role and an inventory correctly works as expected if you needed a proof. I will end up here the concierge talk because SO is not made for that. Simply fix your project.

Comment: @Zeitounator "Simply fix your project" for the 10th time, my project works fine and I added a screenshot that demonstrates such. The "typos" are my efforts to create a mcve that accurately mirrors my production code without including unnecessary details, however, the code does exactly what I said it does and my issue is once again not a syntactical one but a conceptual one. I would appreciate it if you could end this ongoing discussion and give me a chance to hear more constructive responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like your example makes all the sense based on the documentation about [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable):

> Ansible does apply variable precedence, and you might have a use for it. Here is the order of precedence from least to greatest (the last listed variables override all other variables):
>
> 1. command line values (for example, `-u my_user`, these are not variables)
> 2. role defaults (defined in role/defaults/main.yml) [<sup>1</sup>](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id13)
> 3. inventory file or script group vars [<sup>2</sup>](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id14)
> 4. inventory group_vars/all [<sup>3</sup>](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id15)
> 5. playbook group_vars/all [<sup>3</sup>](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id15)
> 6. inventory group_vars/* [<sup>3</sup>](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id15)
> 7. playbook group_vars/* [<sup>3</sup>](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id15)
> 8. inventory file or script host vars [<sup>2</sup>](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id14)
> 9. inventory host_vars/* [<sup>3</sup>](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id15)
> 10. playbook host_vars/* [<sup>3</sup>](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id15)
> 11. host facts / cached set_facts [<sup>4</sup>](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id16)
> 12. play vars
> 13. play vars_prompt
> 14. play vars_files
> 15. role vars (defined in role/vars/main.yml)
> 16. block vars (only for tasks in block)
> 17. task vars (only for the task)
> 18. include_vars
> 19. set_facts / registered vars
> 20. role (and include_role) params
> 21. include params
> 22. extra vars (for example, `-e "user=my_user"`)(always win precedence)

Where you can see that:

- inventory file or script group vars is **3**
- inventory group_vars/* is **4**
- inventory file or script host vars is **8**
- inventory host_vars/* is **9**

---

So in you first trial, you have

- inventory file or script group vars is **3** => `99`
- inventory group_vars/* is **4** => `77`
- inventory file or script host vars is **8** => `88`

So, `88` wins.

---

Then you remove `88`

- inventory file or script group vars is **3** => `99`
- inventory group_vars/* is **4** => `77`

So, `77` wins.

---

And then you add one:

- inventory file or script group vars is **3** => `99`
- inventory group_vars/* is **4** => `77`
- inventory host_vars/* is **9** => `101`

So `101` wins.

Comment: Ah ok, so the "[main:vars] testvar=99" block counts as `group_vars` rather than `host_vars`? I assumed that ansible automatically flattens host group vars like this into host-level variables rather than `group_vars` level variables.

Comment: Yes, and ini section `[some]` is a group, not an host, see: [*Entries in sections `[group_1]` are hosts, members of the group.*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/ini_inventory.html#synopsis)